# Program that can track drawing and make an animation?

Tags: windows, web-apps, drawing, graphic-design, animation

I'm looking for a program in which you could easily draw and than view the process of your drawing.

Answer (score 1):

[Deviantart Muro](https://muro.deviantart.com/) allows you to draw in your browser and after you click "Done" you can go to your "Sta.sh" where you can "Watch Redraw". It even allows you to adapt the speed in which you view your drawing and to watch it from a "Watcher" perspective as well as from an "Artist" perspective.